# Erro inserindo o flatpickr no wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Galera, estou tentando inserir o flatpickr no wordpress mas não aparece o calendário, só aparece o "Select Date..." Alguém sabe me explicar o porque ? O código que eu estou colocando é esse:

```
flatpickr("#inline", {
    inline: true,
    weekNumbers: true
})
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/bower_components/flatpickr/dist/themes/material_green.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr"></script>

<input class="flatpickr" type="text" placeholder="Select Date.." id="inline">
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para quem não conhece o flatpickr aqui está: https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/

Comment: Posta uma imagem ai de como está aparecendo o componente no Browser.

Comment: @hugocsl adicionei uma imagem ao post.